# Why does 'player' go red- Spigot Development

Tags: plugins, minecraft

Following a tutorial to help me with a plugin. When you run /start, I want it to teleport the player to x190 y10 z-71 in-game. I was writing it 'player' goes red. Why??[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlpNX.png)

Comment: You called the player 'target'.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the name of the player variable from `target` to `player`.